# UML generation tools netbeans

Tags: netbeans, uml

How could i create UML projet in Netbeans 7.0

please help

thank you
roshan

Comment: there are no options to create new UML project in netbeans 7.0 but privious there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://java.net/projects/eidos-uml There's great support for UML in NetBeans IDE, read that link for details.

Comment: @Roshan, so how was it? Did that work? I got similar problem here.